# values getting overriden in callbacks inside callback in setInterval method node js

Tags: node.js, callback, setinterval

I have situation where i have an array of employees data and i need to process something parallel for every employee.To implement it and achieve the task i broke the things to chunks to four methods and every method has a callback calling each other and returning callback.I am using

> async.eachSeries

to start the process for each element of the employee array.

In the last method i have to set the setInterval to perform same task if required response is not achieved,this interval is not cleared till the process of repeating task continues to 5 times(if desired value is not received 5 times,but cleared after 5th time).

Now,the problem  happening is that data which i am processing inside setInterval is getting overriden by values of last employees.

So i am not able to keep track of process happening for all the employee Array elements and also the details of processing for last employee  are getting mixed up.

In between the four methods which i am using for performing the task are carrying out the process of saving data to redis , MongoDB , Outside Api's giving response in callback.

Can anyone suggest better way of doing this and also i feel that the problem is happening because i am not returning any callback from SetInterval method().But since that method itself is an asynchronous method so i am unware about how to handle the situation.

```
EmployeeArray




    async.eachSeries() used to process EmployeeArray
```

for each i have Four callBack Medhods .

```
async.eachSeries() {   
        Callback1(){
             Callback2(){
                  Callback3(){
                      Callback4(){ 
                                    SetInterval(No CallBack inside this from my side)
                                  }
                             }
                        }
                   }
        }
```

Comment: This question needs some real code with a real objective described, not partially filled in pseudo-code with a theoretical question.

Answer (score 0):

As per I know the async each function does parallel processing. Also u can use async waterfall to make your code more clean. Try something like this.

```
async.each(openFiles, function(file, callback1) {
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    callback(null, 'one', 'two');
  },
  function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
  // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
    callback(null, 'three');
  },
  function(arg1, callback) {
    // arg1 now equals 'three'
    callback(null, 'done');
  }
], function (err, result) {
  callback1(err);
});
}, function(err){
    //if you come here without error your data is processed
});
```